# Render string as a "label" instead of "input" in ASP.NET MVC 2 using UIHint?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic-data

I tried UIHint("Label") but it doesn't change the behavior. If someone also can point me to a list of possible values for UIHint, that would be awesome!

Comment: You mean you have a piece of read only data that you don't want an input field for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue=true)]` on your property.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a DisplayTemplate Folder in your Shared Folder with Label.ascx?

Comment: No, I was assuming there might be already something core for this.